# How to decode response with zlib in fiddler

Tags: fiddler, content-encoding

I know there is `Response body is encoded. Click to decode` but it dosen't work.

The response I get is encoded by `zlib` not `gzip` and there is no `Content-Encoding: gzip` in response header.

Now I can save the response body to a file and then decode it by `Python`, but I really want to see the pretty content just in `fiddler`.

What should I do?

Comment: Fix your server so it returns the proper content-encoding header?

Comment: @CodeCaster, unfortunately, it is not my server. So I have to research what does it send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough rep. to comment, but I improved PaleNeutron's snippet.

- Fix request decoding
- Added logic to check for the zlib header so we don't double decode and create an empty request/response

In the FiddlerScript tab:

```
public static ContextAction("Force Decode (zlib)")
function AddEncoding(oSessions: Fiddler.Session[]){
    for (var x:int = 0; x < oSessions.Length; x++){
        if (oSessions[x].oRequest.headers["Content-Encoding"]=="zlib"){
            oSessions[x].oRequest.headers["Content-Encoding"]="deflate";
            oSessions[x].utilDecodeRequest();
        }
        if (oSessions[x].oResponse.headers["Content-Encoding"]=="zlib"){
            oSessions[x].oResponse.headers["Content-Encoding"]="deflate";
            oSessions[x].utilDecodeResponse();
        }
    }
    UI.actUpdateInspector(true,true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add or edit headers in Fiddler. Go to the Headers inspector and then select the Unlock for Editing option from the Edit menu. Then right-click on the headers and choose Add or Edit Header in the context menu.

Thus you can add/modify Content-Encoding.

You can also do that in FiddlerScript.

Comment: This is the approach I typically use; you probably want `Content-Encoding: deflate` which matches zlib.

Comment: It works! But the client doesn't work now after I add "Content-Encoding: deflate" in OnBeforeResponse. Is there any method like OnAfterResponse? I just want to view it not change it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to fiddler script

```
public static ContextAction("force decode with deflate")
function AddEncoding(oSessions: Fiddler.Session[]){
    for (var x:int = 0; x < oSessions.Length; x++){
        oSessions[x].utilDecodeRequest();
        oSessions[x].oResponse.headers["Content-Encoding"]="deflate"
        oSessions[x].utilDecodeResponse();
    }
    UI.actUpdateInspector(true,true);
}
```

And `force decode with deflate` choice will appear in the right-click menu.